# Sqlite is inserting only first value

Tags: ios, sqlite, bind

```
-(BOOL)insertAttendees {
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
   const char *insert_stmt = "INSERT INTO ATTENDEE (A_NAME,A_IMAGE,A_EMAIL,A_PHONE,A_BIO) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &db) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
      if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, nil) != SQLITE_OK){
            NSLog(@"[ERROR] SQLITE: Failed to prepare statement! :%s",sqlite3_errmsg(db));
            return NO;
        }
        for (int i=0; i<[attendeeCount[0]integerValue];i++){

            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [arrayOf_AName[0][i] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [arrayOf_AImage[0][i] UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [arrayOf_AEmail[0][i] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [arrayOf_APhone[0][i] UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 5, [arrayOf_ABio[0][i] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

        }
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ERROR) {
            NSLog(@"[ERROR] SQLITE: Failed to insert into database! Error: '%s' ", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        return NO;
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"[ERROR] SQLITE: Failed to open database! Error: '%s' ", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        return NO;
    }
    return  YES;
}
```

Comment: Debugging? Logging? Any details that might help?

Comment: this is working but when i am trying to select all data from the table am getting only one value

Comment: add description of problem and what steps you have taken to diagnose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you are calling `sqlite3_step` only once.

You have to move that call into the `for` loop.

(The horrible indentation of that code might have helped to introduce this bug.)